# jQuery is hiding the wrong table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using some code to hide/reveal tables. All is well except I cannot find how to stop all tables being effected by this code. I have table 1, table 2 and table X, I want table X to be present at all times, however I cannot figure how to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Add device</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        \$(document).ready(function(){
        \$("#myDropdown").change(function(){
        target = \$\(this\).val();
        \$(".tables").hide();
        if(target != 'none'){
            \$("#" + target).show();
        }           
        return false;
        });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
            width:100%;
            display:none;
        }
        #content{
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<table id='none' class='tables' width='100%'>
<tr>
<td>**********TABLE X***********</td>
</tr>
</table>
<body>
<div id="content">
<p align = 'center'>
Are you adding a chassis or a module?</br>
<select id="myDropdown">
<option selected value="t3">Please Select</option>
<option value="t1">Chassis</option>
<option value="t2">Module</option>
</select>
</p>
<table id='t1' align='center' class='tables'>
*********TABLE 1***************
</table>
<table id='t2' align='center' class='tables'>
*********TABLE 2***************
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried playing around with classes and id's to no avail.

Comment: $(".tables").hide(); will hide anything with the tables class.

Comment: Hide on id or use specific classes!

Comment: Hide the tables the proper tables using CSS. Your HTML is badly formed.

Comment: @DaveBriand
Even when I put the table in another class or no class it's still hidden

Comment: One table outside `<body>` , no starting `<form>` tag ? Table without `<td>` `<tr>` , that seems totally invalid

Comment: use id to hide your table as `$("#t1").hide();`

Comment: @Dr.Molle
Escape characters, it's being printed using perl.

Comment: No matter which suggested solution you use, you additionally should add this CSS: `#none{display:table}`

Comment: @Dr.Molle What why is that needed? Also each solution I've tried does not show the table on load, only once I've used the dropdown once at best

Comment: because initially all tables are hidden via CSS: `table{width:100%;display:none;}`

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks, I used that line combined with another answer and it's all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class to table you don't want to hide and use css `.not` selector.

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjj5H/1/)

Code:

HTML:

```
<table id='none' class='tables no-hide-please' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>**********TABLE X***********</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="content">
    <p align = 'center'>
        Are you adding a chassis or a module?</br>
        <select id="myDropdown">
            <option selected value="t3">Please Select</option>
            <option value="t1">Chassis</option>
            <option value="t2">Module</option>
        </select>
    </p>
<table id='t1' align='center' class='tables'>
    <tr>
        <td>*********TABLE 1***************</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<table id='t2' align='center' class='tables'>
    <tr>
        <td>*********TABLE 2***************</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myDropdown").change(function(){
        target = $(this).val();
        $(".tables:not(.no-hide-please)").hide();
        if(target != 'none'){
            $("#" + target).show();
        }           
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
table{
    width:100%;
    //display:none;
}
#content{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, how how could I show table x whilst table 1 and table 2 are hiden on load

Comment: This is the code I used to fix my problem however I uncommented:
display:none;
and added:
#none{display:table}
Which left the table x to load on start and the other two to hide

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding based on the class, not the ID. The class is used on each table, which is why all your tables are being hidden.

Change the jQuery selector to bind to the id of the table you want to hide, and only that one will be hidden.

To hide the first and second table, you can select both.

```
$("#t1, #t2").hide();
```

Or create a class you can reuse called "hidable" and show/hide that. You can then apply that class to tables you want that behaviour to apply to.

```
$(".hideable").hide();

<table id='t1' align='center' class='tables hideable'>
*********TABLE 1***************
</table>
<table id='t2' align='center' class='tables hideable'>
*********TABLE 2***************
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the tables that you wish to be visible permanently:

`<table id='none' class='tables no_hide' width='100%'>`

Change you JQuery selector to this:

`$(".tables:not(.no_hide)").hide();`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.tables:not(#none)').hide();
```

Comment: Because it's bad practice. It'll bind to all tables created in the future too, and hiding those might not be the intention. It's best to bind to the actual tables you want to hide, not just hide all except one, which is unreliable.

Comment: There is nothing in the question related to *tables created in the future*